# Data.table; Update join on a filtered table/values

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am wanting to update a subset of table_a using an update join with `table_b` however after attempting the update join the non-filtered `table_a` does not change at all;

```
dat_a <- 
  data.table(postcode = LETTERS[1:10],
             values = c(1:8,NaN,10))
dat_b <- 
  data.table(postcode = LETTERS[1:10],
             values = c(990:999))
```

Table A and B both have the same postcodes but different values for each. There is a 'NaN' value in table_a which I want to update with the corresponding value in table_b however I don't want to update all the other values in `table_a`.

```
dat_a[is.nan(values)
      ][dat_b,
        values := i.values,
        on = .(postcode)]
```

Does not change the table at all

```
dat_a
    postcode values
 1:        A      1
 2:        B      2
 3:        C      3
 4:        D      4
 5:        E      5
 6:        F      6
 7:        G      7
 8:        H      8
 9:        I    NaN
10:        J     10
```

The operation seems to have worked though so I'm not sure why the specific value did not get updated by reference. What do I need to do differently here?

```
dat_a[is.nan(values)
      ][dat_b,
        values := i.values,
        on = .(postcode)][]

   postcode values
1:        I    998
```

Note;
An alternative is to filter the values in table_b however this is not a good solution for my real dataset as instead of just filtering table_a to a single column of "NaN" values I'll have to filter multiple columns in table_b and all the different values in that table that leads to a 'NaN' result.

E.g. Imagine if instead of just needing to filter by postcode I'd have to filter by (`postcode == "I" & age == 23 & qualification == "bachelors"` then redo this for all the other combinations of those variables that lead to a 'NaN' result)

```
dat_a[dat_b[postcode == "I"],
      values := i.values,
      on = .(postcode)]

dat_a
    postcode values
 1:        A      1
 2:        B      2
 3:        C      3
 4:        D      4
 5:        E      5
 6:        F      6
 7:        G      7
 8:        H      8
 9:        I    998
10:        J     10
```

Comment: By filtering you create another deep copied table that is separate from the original table

Comment: Thank you! That lead me to the solution which should've been kinda obvious (ill post it as a answer) Edit; I see you also posted a answer, ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By filtering you create another deep copied table that is separate from the original table.
Instead of filtering, you can use `fcoalesce` here. It returns the first non-missing value

```
dat_a[dat_b,
      # as numeric to ensure same variable type
      values := fcoalesce(values, as.numeric(i.values)), 
      on = .(postcode)]

dat_a
#>     postcode values
#>  1:        A      1
#>  2:        B      2
#>  3:        C      3
#>  4:        D      4
#>  5:        E      5
#>  6:        F      6
#>  7:        G      7
#>  8:        H      8
#>  9:        I    998
#> 10:        J     10
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont have the exact timings but by avoiding copies this should be faster.

Your other comment lead me to thinking of assigning to a filtered version of the table except that would not be efficient!
i.e. dat_a[is.nan(values)] <- dat_a[....

Answer (score 1):

You could also set up a helper variable in each dataset:

```
dat_a[, repl := is.nan(values)]
dat_b[, repl := TRUE]
dat_a[dat_b, on=.(postcode,repl), values := i.values]

#    postcode values   repl
#      <char>  <num> <lgcl>
# 1:        A      1  FALSE
# 2:        B      2  FALSE
# 3:        C      3  FALSE
# 4:        D      4  FALSE
# 5:        E      5  FALSE
# 6:        F      6  FALSE
# 7:        G      7  FALSE
# 8:        H      8  FALSE
# 9:        I    998   TRUE
#10:        J     10  FALSE
```

While a little clunky, this would allow you to add all sorts of requirements to the join like you requested, in either dataset `a` or `b`. E.g.:

```
dat_a[, repl := is.nan(values) & age == 23 & qualification == "bachelors"]
```

This is then somewhat analogous to a `where` statement in SQL, where instead of specifying a set of criteria to be tested against to find TRUE/FALSE per each possible row that could be returned, you are specifying the TRUE/FALSE manually in each dataset and then inner joining on that predetermined criteria.